# Keycloak is having issue with Angular Js # routing

Tags: javascript, keycloak

I am integrating keycloak.js file with my application. My application URL is http://localhost:8083/#!/

Because of the # in the URL it was not working. So I used   `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` to remove # from the URL, and now Keycloak integration is working.

But now the browser is making a server call when refreshing my URL (for example, to http://localhost:8083/page1) after removing the #.

Can any help me to solve the refresh problem?

Answer (score 0):

when you use html5mode, you need also server side rewrite as written in angular documentation (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location), paragraph **Server Side**.

So if you are able to rewrite URL on the server to root of your application, it will work.

**BUT**

You might get into trouble as I did on EAP 6.4.

If you would want to access some context other than your root, for example

**/root/some/angular/context**

and you weren't logged in, than the rewrite would strip the context and the login fails on missing **OAuth_Token_Request_State**.

The problem is, that the **KeycloakAuthenticatorValve** is called after the **RewriteValve**, which strips the context. If Keycloak would have been called in reverse order, it would all work perfectly. I checked the **KeycloakAdapterConfigDeploymentProcessor**, which is responsible for adding the valve, and it adds the valve at the end of the list instead at the beginning of the list.

To fix this I had to create custom DeploymentProcessor, which ads the **RewriteValve** after the **KeycloakAuthenticatorValve** instead of having the valve registered in jboss-web.xml descriptor.